# How to return all objects in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to get all objects in an array of objects. I've tried searching online for a solution and got some helpful tips. However, it only returns one of the objects and not all of the objects in the array. I can't seem to figure out why?

**Array of objects:**

```
[{"id":"_f939IxLRjn0YVvOEg5SR","type":"multiple","category":"Entertainment: Video Games","question":"Which Sonic the Hedgehog game was originally supposed to be packaged with Sonic 3, but was cut in half due to time constraints?","correct_answer":"Sonic &amp; Knuckles","incorrect_answers":["Sonic 2","Sonic CD","Sonic 3D Blast"]},{"id":"84LQQOeMZqeqYweGXKZ47","type":"multiple","category":"General Knowledge","question":"Which American-owned brewery led the country in sales by volume in 2015?","correct_answer":"D. G. Yuengling and Son, Inc","incorrect_answers":["Anheuser Busch","Boston Beer Company","Miller Coors"]}]
```

**Array.reduce code:**

```
const [quizObj, setQuizObj] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    setQuizObj(() => {
      return allQuiz.reduce((obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, { ...item }), {});
    });
  }, [allQuiz]);
```

**console.log output:**

```
{"id":"84LQQOeMZqeqYweGXKZ47","type":"multiple","category":"General Knowledge","question":"Which American-owned brewery led the country in sales by volume in 2015?","correct_answer":"D. G. Yuengling and Son, Inc","incorrect_answers":["Anheuser Busch","Boston Beer Company","Miller Coors"]}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{item: {"id":"_f939IxLRjn0YVvOEg5SR","type":"multiple","category":"Entertainment: Video Games","question":"Which Sonic the Hedgehog game was originally supposed to be packaged with Sonic 3, but was cut in half due to time constraints?","correct_answer":"Sonic &amp; Knuckles","incorrect_answers":["Sonic 2","Sonic CD","Sonic 3D Blast"]}, {"id":"84LQQOeMZqeqYweGXKZ47","type":"multiple","category":"General Knowledge","question":"Which American-owned brewery led the country in sales by volume in 2015?","correct_answer":"D. G. Yuengling and Son, Inc","incorrect_answers":["Anheuser Busch","Boston Beer Company","Miller Coors"]}}
```

Comment: What were you hoping to get instead?

Comment: I was hoping to get all objects in the array with a custom property

Comment: Can you include the desired output in your question so we can see? It's not clear what exactly you're looking for

Comment: Sure, added my desired output

Comment: Its syntax is invalid. You can't have a value in an object without an associated key.

Comment: Is there a way I can have custom keys for each object?

Comment: @koda guess you can use the `id` as a key for each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to transform an array of objects into a single object, then there should be a way to identify each array item with a unique key in the output object.

**Assumption:**  every array item has an `id` property and each items `id` is unique. If the `id`s aren't unique, the data might be overwritten.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const combinedObj = {};

    allQuiz.forEach((obj) => {
      combinedObj[obj.id] = { ...obj };
    });
  
    return combinedObj; 
});
```

I have intentionally used `.forEach` instead of `.reduce` as it's easier to read. But you can of course stick to `.reduce` to achieve the same result.